# I plugged my display, cooling pad, and wireless mouse to a USB-C Hub; Does the hub need external power?

Tags: usb, power-supply, usb-c, usb-hub

I plugged my USB-C hub to my laptop (from the user manual, the output voltage and current of the USB-C port is 5V and 3A). From the hub, I connected my display through the VGA port; my cooling pad and wireless mouse through the two USB-A port.

The mouse sometimes freezes for a brief moment and the fan in my cooling pad sometimes stops spinning.

My questions are:

1. Is it because my USB-C hub doesn't get enough power? My USB-C hub does have a USB-C port which supports Power Delivery (PD), will my problem can be solved by providing power to the USB-C PD port? (like from a wall adapter, such as a normal phone charger?)
2. If it does, will the power damage my Laptop since the USB-C port on my laptop does not support Power Delivery?

Comment: Check the current requirements of the cooling pad (Documentation, specifications). If it draws more than 3 amps (I think that is likely), then the port will not support the pad.

Comment: Ah yes, I just saw my cooling pad's specification, and it is written it needs 0.38A (facepalm for me). So, a dead-end for me?

Comment: Edit: if I still wanted to connect everything to my USB-C hub, can the power delivery port solve my problem? or is it a dead-end for me?

Comment: I am not sure if Power Delivery will solve your issue. Try powering the USB Hub with an external supply.

Comment: Does plugging power to the USB-C PD port count as "powering the USB-hub with the external power supply"? Sorry if my question was silly, I just don't really understand how it works.. :(

Comment: If you have a number of USB devices, powering the hub should alleviate the power requirements.  It is hard to be more specific because I am not sure of your overall environment - but powered hubs are normally a good idea.

Comment: If a laptop has Type-C port, it means that it is a fairly recent device. Modern laptops are likely to use aggressive power management and would selectively suspend some devices (mice and keyboards in particular) after certain period of inactivity. Resume usually has some time lag.

Comment: @Ale..chenski This happens while I actively using my mouse, I also tried to remove the display and cooling pad from the hub, it runs well